# Can fxc.exe compile HLSL with constant uniform function parameters?

Tags: direct3d, hlsl

With the Effects11 framework and the `fx_5_0` target profile, you can create functions which take uniform variables as parameters and compile them with constant values for those variables. For example:

```
void colorVS(float4 positionL : POSITION,
             uniform float4 color,
             out float4 position : SV_Position,
             out float4 vertexColor : COLOR) {
  position = mul(positionL, viewProjectionMatrix);
  vertexColor = color;
}

VertexShader redShader = CompileShader(vs_5_0, colorVS(float4(1,0,0,1)));
VertexShader greenShader = CompileShader(vs_5_0, colorVS(float4(0,1,0,1)));

technique11 RedTechnique { pass {
  SetVertexShader(redShader);
} }

technique11 GreenTechnique { pass {
  SetVertexShader(greenShader);
} }
```

Now, I'm not advocating this practice, but it's what I'm working with as my task is to port an existing project from Effects11 to straight HLSL. The generated assembly for `greenShader` using `fx_5_0` (unoptimized) contains:

```
dcl_temps 1
itof r0.xyzw, l(0, 1, 0, 1)
mov o1.xyzw, r0.xyzw
```

It just sets the constant value in a temp register. I could not however discover a syntax to accomplish the same thing when targeting a `vs_5_0` (or any other non-FX) profile. What ends up happening, by simply passing `colorVS` as the entry point, is this:

```
// cbuffer $Params
// {
//   float4 color;                      // Offset:    0 Size:    16
// }

dcl_constantbuffer cb0[1], immediateIndexed
// ...
mov o1.xyzw, cb0[0].xyzw
```

Is it possible for me to compile these shaders with FXC using only the `vs_5_0` profile and pass the constant values?

Comment: Just a note that with an optimized compile with the fx_5_0 profile, it skips setting the temp register and just uses a single instruction `mov o1.xyzw, l(0,1.000000,0,1.000000)`.